# Strict parameter matching in backbone.js router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I've got a router defined as such:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    // catch-all for undefined routes
    "*notfound" : "notFound",
  },

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.route("my_resource/clear_filters", 'clearFilters');
    this.route("my_resource/:id", 'show');
  },

  show: function(id){
    console.log('show', id);
  },

  clearFilters: function() {
    console.log('clearFilters');
  },

  notFound: function() {
    console.log('notFound');
  },
});

var app = {};
app.MyRouter = new MyRouter();
Backbone.history.start({silent: true});
```

Thus the following URLs would map as:

```
var opts = {trigger: true};
app.MyRouter.navigate('/foo', opts);                       // logged -> 'notFound'
app.MyRouter.navigate('/my_resource/123', opts);           // logged -> 'show', '123'
app.MyRouter.navigate('/my_resource/clear_filters', opts); // logged -> 'clearFilters'
app.MyRouter.navigate('/my_resource/some_thing', opts);    // logged -> 'show', 'some_thing'
```

How can I restrict the `my_resource/:id` route to only match on numeric parameters so that `app.MyRouter.navigate('/my_resource/some_thing')` is handled by `notFound`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route):

> **route** `router.route(route, name, [callback])`
>
> Manually create a route for the router, The `route` argument may be a routing string or regular expression. Each matching capture from the route or regular expression will be passed as an argument to the callback.

So you can always say things like:

```
this.route(/my_resource\/(\d+)/, 'show')
```

in your router's `initialize` if you need finer grained control over the routes than Backbone's string patterns give you.

Comment: Yes, I knew routes could use regex, but as I understand it you can use either regex or named params - you can't have a named regex - so there's no way to pass the matched regex to the callback function.

Comment: "Each matching capture from the route or regular expression will be passed as an argument to the callback." Backbone internally replaces the `:name` things with regex groups when converting the routes to regexes. Or are are you trying to send several route patterns to the same route handler and you want to know which route is being triggered inside the handler?

Comment: "Backbone internally replaces the :name things with regex groups when converting the routes to regexes"

Got it! That was the missing piece. Thanks :)

Comment: The `:name` notation is a bit misleading as the route parameters aren't actually named at all, they're all positional. The names in the route are just for documentation purposes really.